# Using -skip_threshold with mpeg4 encoder in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webcam

Can anybody please shed a light on subj - I didn't find anything useful on the net.
What I'm trying to do is to eliminate duplicate frames during webcam stream recording. I know about existance of "scene" filter, but I came across this option in codec help reference..

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=mpeg4
```

..and I'd like to test it as well.

My test command looks like:

```
Ffmpeg -f dshow -pixel_format yuyv422 -framerate 10 -video_size 800x600 -i video="*my webcam*" -vcodec mpeg4 -skip_threshold 20 out.mkv
```

Looks like ffmpeg just ignores this skipping option. Maybe I need to use different profile or to specify some parameters? Don't know. 
Would appreciate any help.

*ffmpeg version 4.2.2 (git-2020-05-15-b18fd2b)

**Please pardon my english - it's not my native language.

Have a nice day.